# Menu will not center

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to make my menu / navigationbar to center horizontally. I can't quite figure out what I've done wrong / forgotten. Also after my last li is right padding. How do I remove it?

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="header"></div>
   <div class="Header"></div>
   <ul class="menu">
     <li>Home</li>
     <li>Over mij</li>
     <li>Mijn diensten</li>
     <li>Contact</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
}

.menudiv {
  width: 80%;
  border: 1px red solid;
  margin: auto;
}

.menu {
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px red solid;
  position: relative;
  display:inline-block;         
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  left: 50%;
  color: black;
  padding-left: 20%;
  padding-right: 18%;
  min-width: 80%;
  max-width: 80%;       
}

.menu li {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  padding-right: 5%;
}

.menu li:after {
  content: '/';
  padding-left: 20px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sdzLn5hd/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, **first of all**, are you sure this is how your `HTML` code should be?

```
<div class="Header">
</div>  
<ul class="menu">
   <li>Home </li>
   <li>Over mij </li>
   <li>Mijn diensten </li>
   <li>Contact </li>
</ul>
```

instead of :

```
<div class="Header">
    <ul class="menu">
       <li>Home </li>
       <li>Over mij </li>
       <li>Mijn diensten </li>
       <li>Contact </li>
    </ul>  
</div>
```

*I'd suggest you to check this first.*

**Secondly**, your `menu` is centered (the menu-items are not. Maybe that's what you meant). Just taking a look at your `CSS` and adding `background-color` to it makes it all clear.

```css
.wrapper {

    width: 100%;

}

.menudiv {

    width: 80%;

    border: 1px red solid;

    margin: auto;

}

.menu {


    border: 1px red solid;

    padding: 55px 0;

    position: relative;

    display:inline-block;

    transform: translateX(-50%);

    left: 50%;

    color: black;

    width: 80%;

}

.menu li {

    float: left;

    display: block;

    padding-right: 5%;

}

.menu li:after {

    content:'/';

    padding-left: 20px;

}

div.wrapper {
    
    background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
  
        <title>Webdesign Maarten</title>
        
    
    
    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="header">
                <!-- hier image te zetten JQuery prefereerbaar Sliding !-->
            </div>
            <div class="Header">
                <!-- menu float left indent met icoon gecentreerd opzicht v wrap. no list style -->
            </div>
            <ul class="menu">
                <li>Home</li>
                <li>Over mij</li>
                <li>Mijn diensten</li>
                <li>Contact</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Now, onto the solutions, I am not sure what exactly you are looking for, but I can suggest you two possible solutions.

**Solution 1:**

Modify the `.menu li` class as below :

```
.menu li {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}
```

See this below :

```css
.wrapper {
    width: 100%;
}
.menudiv {
    width: 80%;
    border: 1px red solid;
    margin: auto;
}
.menu {
    border: 1px red solid;
    padding: 55px 0;
    position: relative;
    display:inline-block;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    left: 50%;
    color: black;
    width: 80%;
}
.menu li {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}
.menu li:after {
    content:'/';
    padding-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<title>Webdesign Maarten</title>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="header">
            <!-- hier image te zetten JQuery prefereerbaar Sliding !-->
        </div>
        <div class="Header">
            <!-- menu float left indent met icoon gecentreerd opzicht v wrap. no list style -->
            <ul class="menu">
                <li>Home</li>
                <li>Over mij</li>
                <li>Mijn diensten</li>
                <li>Contact</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**Solution 2:**

Modify the `.menu` and `.menu li` class as below :

```
.menu {
        border: 1px red solid;
        padding: 55px 0;
        position: relative;
        display:inline-block;
        transform: translateX(-50%);
        left: 50%;
        color: black;
        width: 80%;
        text-align: center;   /*Add this property*/
    }

.menu li {
        display: block;
        text-align: center;
    }
```

See this below :

```css
.wrapper {
    width: 100%;
}
.menudiv {
    width: 80%;
    border: 1px red solid;
    margin: auto;
}
.menu {
    border: 1px red solid;
    padding: 55px 0;
    position: relative;
    display:inline-block;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    left: 50%;
    color: black;
    width: 80%;
    text-align: center;
}
.menu li {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}
.menu li:after {
    content:'/';
    padding-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<title>Webdesign Maarten</title>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="header">
            <!-- hier image te zetten JQuery prefereerbaar Sliding !-->
        </div>
        <div class="Header">
            <!-- menu float left indent met icoon gecentreerd opzicht v wrap. no list style -->
            <ul class="menu">
                <li>Home</li>
                <li>Over mij</li>
                <li>Mijn diensten</li>
                <li>Contact</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hello Satwik. Thank you for your answer. I have however fixed it in the meantime like this https://jsfiddle.net/r3fzfhpy/. I have implemented your help into the original code though. Thank you :)

Comment: @MaartenWachters Well, I am glad to be of help. However, I need to inform you that in your solution in jsfiddle, the `ul` has a `padding-left`. You need to remove it (See it in inspect element).  See here without the `padding-left`-> http://jsfiddle.net/jxu4wow3/

Comment: Hey @Satwik Nadkarny. Thank you for getting back to me. As for what you said, are you saying I need to add an aditional `padding-left: 0px;`? Because in my code I have not given my UL any padding-left. Thank-you.

Comment: Okay I have watched your fiddle a couple of times and see what you mean. Thank-you for your help :)

Comment: @MaartenWachters Yes. because it has a `padding-left` by default which you need to cancel out.

Answer (score 1):

To remove padding from the last li item, you need to target it:

```
.menu li:last-child {
    padding-right: 0;
}
```

Looking at your code, I can't really figure out what is that you need. Html is all messed up. Why do you close header div before menu?

Comment: Hello Kristine. Indeed my HTML was all over the place, somehow I managed to translate it  poorly from my code to stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

Change the `li` to display inline-block, target the last of the `li`'s with `:last-child`:

```
.menu {
    text-align:center;
    border: 1px red solid;
    padding: 55px 0;
    position: relative;
    display:inline-block;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    left: 50%;
    color: black;
    width: 80%;
 }

.menu li {
    display:inline-block;
    padding-right: 5%;
}
.menu li:last-child {
    padding-right: none;
}
```

### [JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ImagineStudios/eexo22cm/)

Comment: Thank you for the reply Jacob.

In the meantime though, I managed to fix it like this

https://jsfiddle.net/r3fzfhpy/

Answer (score 1):

Here is the best I could do. I added flexbox style to the ul, and removed some padding to get it centered.

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sdzLn5hd/7/

**HTML**

```
<title>Webdesign Maarten</title>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="header">
            <!-- hier image te zetten JQuery prefereerbaar Sliding !-->
        </div>
        <div class="Header">
            <!-- menu float left indent met icoon gecentreerd opzicht v wrap. no list style -->
        </div>
        <ul class="menu">
            <li>Home</li>
            <li>Over mij</li>
            <li>Mijn diensten</li>
            <li>Contact</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper {
    width: 100%;
}
.menudiv {
    width: 80%;
    border: 1px red solid;
    margin: auto;
}
.menu {
    border: 1px red solid;
    padding: 55px 0;
    position: relative;
    display:flex;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    left: 50%;
    color: black;
    width: 80%;
}
.menu li {
    margin:auto;
    display: block;
}
.menu li:after {
    content:'/';
    padding-left: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply Jesse. I'm not sure what the flexbox does. I however after fiddeling some more found a way. https://jsfiddle.net/r3fzfhpy/

Answer (score 1):

put in your .menu

```
.menu { text-align:center; }

.menu li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 5%;
}
```

Your `float:left` will always send the elements to their furthest left possible.

and add this line in your css (remove the last '/' and padding)

```
.menu li:last-child:after {
    content: '';
    padding-left: 0px;
}
```

see here: https://jsfiddle.net/sdzLn5hd/5/

Answer (score 1):

https://jsfiddle.net/sdzLn5hd/9/ something like this perhaps is what you're looking for

```
<title>Webdesign Maarten</title>



<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="header">
            <!-- hier image te zetten JQuery prefereerbaar Sliding !-->


        <ul class="menu">
            <li>Home</li>
            <li>Over mij</li>
            <li>Mijn diensten</li>
            <li>Contact</li>
        </ul>
             </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

removing some unneeded tags in your html

Answer (score 0):

**To center text and inline elements, a block parent should have `text-align: center` applied.**

Since you have this tagged as HTML5, I would like to provide you with a more semantic approach to your HTML too. There were a lot of extra styling properties left over from you trying to get this to work, so I re-wrote your CSS thus far (including a few more changes that I try to explain in comments). You can see my code in the snippet below:

```css
* { margin: 0px; padding: 0px; } /* Simple CSS reset */

header { display: block; text-align: center; }

h1,
nav > ul {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px red solid;
    padding: 20px 0px;
    width: 80%;
}

nav > ul { border-top: none; }
nav > ul > li { display: inline; }
nav > ul > li:after { content: "/" }
nav > ul > li:last-child:after { content: "" } /* Remove trailing separator */

nav > ul > li > a {
    padding: 15px; /* Padding here is important for touch */
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}
nav > ul > li > a:hover { text-decoration: underline; }
```

```html
<header>
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: Thank you man. I actually forgot how to remove the trailing on the last child so this is welcome. 

Your code looks so much diffrent then mine though, CSS wise.

Comment: Yeah, since I changed the HTML, the selectors had to look very different. Then, there was a slew of changes made to simplify and future-proof the styling for the sake of a good StackOverflow answer. (that is, an answer that should help other people on the site as well) Sorry if it looks like I went overboard. I mean no disrespect.